# Multiple loading of webpages in webview is slower

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I am developing an sample iPad app where I am displaying some webapages in `UIWebview` , the code is working properly.But I think the webpages are taking too much time to load in to `UIWebview`.My code is as below:

```
-(void)createWebView
{

    //******************** First Webview*********

    firstWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    firstWebView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 50, 350, 470);
    firstWebView.delegate=self;
    firstIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    firstIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    firstIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.firstWebView addSubview:firstIndicator];
    [firstIndicator startAnimating];
    firstWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
     NSURL *firstUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.techtree.com"];
     NSURLRequest *firstRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:firstUrl];
    [firstWebView loadRequest:firstRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:firstWebView]; 

    //******************* Second Webview*********

    secondWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    secondWebView.frame=CGRectMake(405, 50, 350, 470);
    secondWebView.delegate=self;

    secondIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    secondIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    secondIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.secondWebView addSubview:secondIndicator];
    [secondIndicator startAnimating];
    secondWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *secondUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
    NSURLRequest *secondRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:secondUrl];
    [secondWebView loadRequest:secondRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:secondWebView]; 


    //****************** Third Webview************

    thirdWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    thirdWebView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 528, 350, 470);
    thirdWebView.delegate=self;


    thirdIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    thirdIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    thirdIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.thirdWebView addSubview:thirdIndicator];
    [thirdIndicator startAnimating];

    thirdWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *thirdUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    NSURLRequest *thirdRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:thirdUrl];
    [thirdWebView loadRequest:thirdRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:thirdWebView];

    //***************** Fourth Webview************
    fourthWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    fourthWebView.frame=CGRectMake(405,528, 350, 470);
    fourthWebView.delegate=self;


    fourthIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    fourthIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    fourthIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.fourthWebView addSubview:fourthIndicator];
    [fourthIndicator startAnimating];

    fourthWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *fourthUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
    NSURLRequest *fourthRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fourthUrl];
    [fourthWebView loadRequest:fourthRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:fourthWebView];


    //******************** Memory Managemt **********
    [firstWebView release];
    [secondWebView release];
    [thirdWebView release];
    [fourthWebView release];


}
```

So how can I make it more faster, please guide me.

Comment: How much time is it taking? And are you comparing the performance of your implementation with the time necessary to load 4 different pages in Safari (which we should assume will be the best performance). In my experience, loading content into WebViews is slower than I'd like, even when the content is local HTML. Nothing you're doing looks very complicated or wrong. So you should do some performance tests in Safari to make sure you've properly set your expectations about what is possible.

Comment: So do i have to use NSOperationQueue or Any threading for this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use NSOpertaionQueue or GCD queue is another options